# What the is correct form for a Hindu Pushup

Tags: push-ups

According to my understanding a hindu pushup is as follows:

- start from a "V" pushup position
- bend your elbows to lower your head towards the groud while keeping your hips locked
- as you approach the ground, straighten your body
- curl your back, while using your arms to push your chest up
- return to starting position (*in what way*)

  - [reverse the movement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DuHnnh3nDJU) **OR**
  - [while keeping your arms locked, raise your hips](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ndOPrcoUt8)

**Questions**

Is there a (more) correct way of returning to the starting position?

What are the benefits of either way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just keep my arms locked and raise my hips back to the start. Reversing the movement is much, much harder, which of course brings its own benefits but to me changes the point of the exercise. What I want to get out of it is shoulder strength and flexibility across a wide range of motion, which doing it in only one direction does. The other way isn't wrong, just a harder variant.